# Longest Palindrome Substring (LeetCode) solution using expandAroundCenter function, how isn't O(n^3)?

Tags: java, algorithm, palindrome

How it's not O(n^3) since inside each for loop we do 2 while loops one for len1 and other for len2 ?

The below solution is working outputs the palindrome correctly. But I am confused.

Here is the solution from LeetCode:

```
public String longestPalindrome(String s) {
    if (s == null || s.length() < 1) return "";

    int start = 0, end = 0;
    //Loop 1
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        //Loop 2
        int len1 = expandAroundCenter(s, i, i);

        //Loop 3
        int len2 = expandAroundCenter(s, i, i + 1);
        int len = Math.max(len1, len2);
        if (len > end - start) {
            start = i - (len - 1) / 2;
            end = i + len / 2;
        }
    }
    return s.substring(start, end + 1);
}

private int expandAroundCenter(String s, int left, int right) {
    int L = left, R = right;
    while (L >= 0 && R < s.length() && s.charAt(L) == s.charAt(R)) {
        L--;
        R++;
    }
    return R - L - 1;
}
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You might have got confused with `expandAroundCenter` running twice.

`expandAroundCenter` function is O(n). It is being run twice but, it is being run in sequence. So it is like O(2n) rather than O(n^2).

And as expandAroundCenter function is being called inside a for loop :
`T(n) = n x 2n = 2n^2`
So, time complexity is O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

The argument is quite straight forward:

- the outer loop is `∈ O(n)`
- the two inner loops (calls to `expandAroundCenter(...)`) run in sequence, not nested. Thus, their complexity can be added up

  - for the inner loop, the worst-case scenario is that it expands from the center of the `String` outwards, i.e. `left` and `right` are set to `n/2`. In this case, the inner loop can at most iterate `n/2`-times since then either `left < 0` or `right >= n`. Thus, overall the inner loop is `∈ O(n)`

In total, we get `O(n) (outer loop) * 2 * O(n) (inner loops in sequence) ∈ O(n^2)`

---

Some remarks on the code:

- While possible, it is unusual in java to declare more than one variable in one line. Thus

  ```
  int start = 0, end = 0;
  ```

  should be

  ```
  int start = 0;
  int end = 0;
  ```

  This change is only code style choice and has no effect on byte code. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63540137/whats-the-difference-between-int-x-int-y-and-int-x-y) for details.
- optional braces around one-line statements should never be omitted. This can be a source of nasty bugs if we later on want to add a line and forget to include the the needed braces. Thus

  ```
  if (s == null || s.length() < 1) return "";
  ```

  should be re-written to

  ```
  if (s == null || s.length() < 1) {
      return "";
  }
  ```
- variable names should alwasy start with a lowercase letter (`L` -> `l`, `R` -> `r`).
- variables should have meaningful names. `l` and `r` are not really meaningful. Thus I propose the following refactoring:

  - renaming parameters `left` and `right` to `leftStart` and `rightStart`
  - renaming parameters `l` and `r` to `currentLeft` and `currentRight`